# How can I restore a downloaded Zoho Creator backup file on a separate Zoho profile?

Tags: backup, restore, zoho

Good day all,
For the purposes of Business Continuity I have investigated whether I can download a backup file from one Zoho instance / profile, to another brand new Zoho Creator instance / profile.

The idea is to mitigate risk if my main profile is somehow ransomed or hijacked.

But from what I can see, there is no option to restore a downloaded backup into Zoho.

Please can someone give me some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure about using one of the backup files, it is possible to export an application schema to a deluge file from one account and create an equivalent application on a different account by uploading the deluge file to the new account.

```
Settings->Application IDE->Export
```

Note, the data won't be included in this operation.  To include the data, it will need to be exported also.  I think there are several methods to do the data export/import.